# Need to call java.net.HttpURLConnection.disconnect() after using connection?

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I'm using `java.net.HttpURLConnection` on Android (API 16). I use `connect()` and then `getInputStream()` to obtain an `InputStream` to read data from the connection. After I use the `InputStream` (i.e. consume the data), I `close()` it.

The question is: does this also closes the underlying `HttpURLConnection` (as if by calling `disconnect()` on it)? My guess is not, but I just want to confirm this. The more general question is: Do I need to call java.net.HttpURLConnection.disconnect() when the connection is no longer useful?

The thing is that I have a method to open a `HttpURLConnection` to a given host. The signature is: `InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String stringURL, String method)`. That returns an `InputStream`, which the caller uses to read data from the connection, but if I call `disconnect()` from within the body of that method, then the `InputStream` is closed and becomes useless (I have confirmed this). But if, on the other hand, the connection isn't closed when I call `close()` on the `InputStream`, from the caller, then I will have a connection wasting resources.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `disconnect()` does close the underlying streams if they are still open, but it additionally releases the connection's resources back to the connection pool, so it is still a good idea to call it when you are able (and finished with the connection) even if you are closing the streams discretely elsewhere.

Comment: But it doesn´t work the other way around, does it? i.e. closing the underlying streams (in this case the `InputStream`), doesn't `disconnect()` the `HttpURLConnection`, am I right?

Comment: Thanks. What do you suggest then, to be able to `disconnect()` in my case? Given that, once `InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String stringURL, String method)` returns, I no longer have a reference to the connection (I could of course return a wrapper object with the `InputStream` and the `HttpURLConnection`, but perhaps there is a more elegant solution).

Comment: One owns the other, no need to return both.  Return just the `HttpURLConnection` once you've set it up and let the caller get the stream and read data.  You probably want to expose the connection anyway so information like the return code is available as well.